# Imprecision in Approximating Pi using Monte Carlo Method

Tags: c++, algorithm, numerical-methods

Area of the circle = Pi * R^2 and the Area of the square = 4 * R^2.
             If we divide the area of the circle by the area of the square we get Pi / 4.

Let's have a square and an inscribed circle in it. We generate points with random coordinates and then count their number in each of the areas.
 
Then Pi = 4 * (# points in Circle) / (# points in Square).

Here is an attempt at approximating Pi with the above method:

```
#include <iostream>     /* std::cout */
#include <iomanip>      /* std::setprecision */
#include <random>       /* std::uniform_int_distribution; std::mt19937 */

/* Check if point (x,y) is inside a circle with radius: r, at O(0,0). */
bool isInside (double x, double y, double r) { return (x*x + y*y) <= r*r; }

double approximatePi (double s, int sample_size)
{
    std::mt19937 gen;                   /* Generate random number in [-s/2 : s/2]. */
    std::uniform_int_distribution<double> dis(-s/2, s/2);

    int count = 0;                      /* Number of points in the circle. */ 
    for (int i = 0; i < sample_size; ++i)
    {
        double x = dis(gen); 
        double y = dis(gen);

        if (isInside(x, y, s/2))        /* Radius of inscribed circle = side / 2. */
        {
            ++count;
        }
    }
    /* Pi = 4 * (# points in Circle) / (# points in Square). */
    return (double) 4 * count / sample_size;    
}

int main()
{
    double side = 10.0;                 /* Square side. */
    int sample_size = 10000;            /* Number of tries. */

    std::cout <<"Pi ~ "<< std::fixed << std::setprecision(6) << approximatePi(side, sample_size) << '\n';
}
```

Expected result: `Pi ~ 3.141592`

Actual result: `Pi ~ 2.611200`

Why am I not getting the expected result? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The effect of [`std::uniform_int_distribution<double>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) is **undefined behavior**, because `double` is not an integer type.

Change it to [`std::uniform_real_distribution<double>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution).

Comment: Surprised that something like that wouldn't throw a warning.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan indeed!  I couldn't compile the code due to a `static_assert`.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan it is not easy for compiler to issue a warning here. It is just a standard library template, and compiler will not have specific knowledge about it's limitations. Standard itself should have mandated `static_assert` on `is_integral` for the argument, but alas, it did not. I consider it a defect.

Comment: Fair enough.  You've got the real distribution as an alternative so good on you.  Overloading the real types to CT would be nice of the library people though.